# Can't set field in bean object

Tags: jakarta-ee, javabeans

I need to create bean objects and keep them in one place(List). Objects should be shared for all users. But when i set field and then call some function on that object i got null pointer.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;
import javax.inject.Inject;
import javax.inject.Named;
import javax.inject.Singleton;
import javax.naming.InitialContext;
import javax.naming.NamingException;

import com.skoczo.db.dao.PlaceDao;
import com.skoczo.db.entity.Place;
import com.skoczo.util.PlaceWrapper;

@Singleton
@Named
public class PlaceManager {
    private List<PlaceWrapper>  places;

    @Inject
    private PlaceDao placeDao;

    public List<PlaceWrapper> getPlaces() throws NamingException
    {
        if(places == null) {
            initialize();
        }

        return places;
    }

    @PostConstruct
    private void initialize() throws NamingException {
        places = new ArrayList<PlaceWrapper>();
        for(Place p : placeDao.findAll()) {
            PlaceWrapper pw = (PlaceWrapper) InitialContext.doLookup("java:module/PlaceWrapper");
            pw.setPlace(p); <-- ####### problematic place ########
            places.add(pw);
        }
    }
}
```

I set Place object in my wrapper but when i call some function on PlaceWrapper object Place is null.

Place class:

```
@Stateless(name="PlaceWrapper")
public class PlaceWrapper implements Serializable{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 932851913058781818L;

    @Inject
    private AudioManagerData audioManagerData;

    @Inject
    private PlaceDao placeDao;

    public void setPlace(Place p) {
        this.p = p;
    }

    public void setVolume(int vol) throws IOException {

        audioManagerData.setVol(getPlace().getSoundCard(), vol);
        setVol(vol);
    }

    public int getVolume() throws Exception {
        if (getVol() == -1) {
            setVol(audioManagerData.getVol(getPlace().getSoundCard()));
        }
        return getVol();
    }

    private int vol = -1;
    private Station station;
    private String song;
    private Place p;
......
```

Screen after setPlace method call. Place still null
[image]

During execute PlaceWrapper object method, place object is null
[image]

Comment: Did you notice, that the PlaceWrapper Objects you are looking at have a different ID? ... Without regard to your actual problem: To me it looks like you are totally mixing up the different layers in your application. Also, you should not use @Stateless Session Beans to hold a state, that's not what they are meant for.

Comment: I saw that ids are different but this is the only place where i create PlaceWrapper objects. What should i change to create PlaceWrapper beans properly?

Comment: I changed Stateless to Stateful. Now it looks ok. Could i have any problems using Stateful ?

Answer (score 0):

You are getting null because PlaceWrapper is a proxy object for a stateless ejb, so it can't hold state between method calls. Each method call is executed against different instances of your PlaceWrapper because there is an ejb poll behind your proxy.

You can change scope do Session, it will work, but it's wrong. I believe you are over engineering your solution and that you don't need an ejb at all. You can simply make PlaceWrapper a CDI managed bean, by removing @Stateless.